# Google Maps API data.setStyle not showing icons on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a little app using the Google Maps JS API. I'm using the data layer to load a bunch of points from a GeoJSON file. The file seems to be loading properly, and the map is displaying, but the icons that are set in the map.data.setstyle() won't show...

Below is my HTML, CSS, and JS. I've been looking at this for 2 days, and I can't figure out what's going wrong. Thank you in advance!

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.000, -120.000),
      zoom: 7
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    map.data.loadGeoJson('/map.json');
    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
      var theaterName = feature.getProperty('name');
      return {
        icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png",
        visible: true,
        clickable: true,
        title: theaterName
      };
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});
```

JSON

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
  {
   "type": "Feature", 
   "properties": {
   "rentrak_id": "9183", "name": "Palm Theatre", "address": "817 Palm St, San Luis Obispo, CA"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [35.2815558, -120.6638196]
  }
},
{
"type": "Feature", 
"properties": {
  "rentrak_id": "8961", "name": "King City 3", "address": "200 Broadway St, King City, CA"},
"geometry": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [36.21372, -121.1261771]
}
},
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {
"rentrak_id": "5549", "name": "Van Buren 3 DI", "address": "3035 Van Buren Blvd, Riverside, CA"},
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [33.9113137, -117.4364228]
}},
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {
"rentrak_id": "990802", "name": "CGV Cinemas LA", "address": "621 S Western Ave, Los Angeles, CA"},
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [34.0626656, -118.3093961]
}},
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {
"rentrak_id": "5521", "name": "Rancho Niguel 7", "address": "25471 Rancho Niguel Rd, Laguna Niguel, CA"},
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [33.5560509, -117.68533]
}}]}
```

**EDIT::**

So, my script is working when I use this file: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week

Which makes me think there is something wrong with my local json file... However when I step through the javascript, I can look at each feature and check for the properties and geometries, and they seem to be correctly loaded into the google.maps.feature objects. So, I still have no idea why the points wouldn't be showing up.

Comment: Your script as it is works as expected for me, please create a demo or post `map.json`

Comment: With your script and your json file each feature has correct latitude and wrong longitude which is set to -90. At least that is what I see in console.log

Comment: Blahh!! Thank you! Yes, the longitude and latitude are in the wrong order.. so nothing was showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates need to be in longitude then latitude order in the geojson... SO SILLY!!! Guess that's a good lesson in reading the documentation thoroughly.

Comment: Unbelievable!  The point coordinate is backwards from all other use cases!

Answer (score 10):

You are using boolean values as strings: `'true'` instead of `true`. So call to `setStyle` should be:

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var theaterName = feature.getProperty('name');
  return {
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png",
    visible: true,
    clickable: true,
    title: theaterName
  };
});
```

**Update:** Your json file has switched lat/lng coordinates. There should be

```
"coordinates": [-118.3093961, 34.0626656]
```

instead of

```
"coordinates": [34.0626656, -118.3093961]
```

That was the reason I got objects which have values `xy, -90`.

See [GeoJSON specs](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html): *The order of elements must follow x, y, z order (easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a projected coordinate reference system, or longitude, latitude, altitude for coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system).*

So, Google Maps API uses lat/lng, for GeoJSON file coordinates it should be lng/lat.

Comment: This of course is correct, but will not break the script. The API obviously didn't check the type of the boolean values, a string `'true'` will be evaluated as a boolean `true`, so it would only give a undesired result with the string `'false'` (which also be evaluated as a boolean `true`)

Comment: I tried changing the strings, but unfortunately didn't fix the problem. I'm going to post my json file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're defining the markers but just not setting the map with them.

Try:
    theaterName.setMap(map);

To set the markers on the map.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using markers. I'm trying to use the new google maps data layer to load in a bunch of geospatial data at once using .loadGeoJson. theaterName is just a string, not a marker, so I don't think this is the issue.